# monitor process for failure

Tags: unix, ocaml, system

I am working on a simple fuzzing tool that involves generating valid instances of some file type and monitoring the program under test for failure. A key component to this tool is a process monitor module: This module should provide functions that, given a strings representing a program path and arguments (e.g., `corrupt.py` and `random_file.wav`) indicates if calling `currupt.py random_file.wav` triggers some error.

**What's the simplest way to define a function that monitors such a process for hanging or throwing an error in OCaml?** I plan to run such a function on loop, so diverting side effects (e.g., content printed to std.out) is critical. The type signature of such a function should be something along the lines of bytes -> int, where int has some associated meaning (e.g., 0 -> healthy exit).

Additionally, I understand that the halting problem makes it impossible to tell if halting is unexpected behavior or not, so I'm fine with drawing the line at an arbitrary wait time.

Comment: Exit code says not much often. Many people ``try ... catch(..} {} return 0;`` in main. I doubt you can make it generic without knowing what the application under test is supposed to do. E.g. supposed to stop? Then, there are already a lot of (free) test suites which do similar stuff around... simply pick one you like.

Comment: "there are already a lot of (free) test suites which do similar stuff around" I'm doing this for fun, not originality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may start with the Unix "High-level process and redirection management" functions, e.g., `create_process prog args new_stdin new_stdout new_stderr` is a generic function that will create a process that runs a program, and it allows you to redirect the channels. The created process will run asynchronously, so you can either peek it with `waitpid`'s `WNOHANG` flag, or just block until it ends (probably the latter shouldn't work for you).

Probably, the following interface should suffice your needs:

```
 module Monitor : sig 

    val start : string -> t
    val terminate : t -> unit

    val on_finish : t -> (int -> unit) -> unit

    ... 
 end
```

or you can just simplify it to

```
  val monitor : string -> (int -> 'a) -> 'a
```

if you don't want to have to manage monitor instances.

Alternatively, you can take a look at the `Lwt` [high-level process management library](https://ocsigen.org/lwt/2.7.0/api/Lwt_process). It might save you quite a few keystrokes. There is also an alternative [async unix library](https://github.com/janestreet/async_unix) from Janestreet, that you may try.

Comment: If you are monitoring processes which may not terminate or may not terminate cleanly then I highly recommend the Lwt_process module @ivg mentions. It makes it much simpler to manage processes which may behave poorly. If you are fuzzing then it also makes it relatively straightforward to run multiple versions of the executable concurrently, potentially reducing the time needed to complete your testing.

Comment: Also, with `Lwt` (or any other monadic IO library) it would be much easier to handle side-effects, like feeding input and handling IO (including networking). The reason is two-fold: first IO monad operations are composable, that makes reasoning about the program much easier. Second, both Async and Lwt are well-established modern libraries that provide extended functionality on top of the standard library. It is hard to advise one or another library, but I would suggest sticking to Lwt for research/fun project, and to Async for the industrial grade projects.